# Studying the nature of an improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals

How can I determine the nature of this integral and also, how can I calculate it?

I've been trying to do it for like an hour, but I can't figure it out.

$$
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x \ln x}{x} dx
$$

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's your definition of "Nature"?

Comment: By nature I mean if it's either divergent or convergent. I've tried to calculate the undefined integral and I don't know how to do it. I think that if it was (cos x)/x only I'd knew how to do it, but with ln I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Use integration by parts integrating $\cos x$ and differentiating $\frac{\ln x}{x}$. Then the remaining integral is absolutely convergent.

Comment: I've managed to do it this way. Thanks :)